A quick and simple method to capture a screen area to clipboard?
Before upgrading to Ubuntu 24, I was used to pressing Shift + Ctrl + PrtSc to select an area on the screen, and get it pasted to the clipboard. Now it doesn't seem to work anymore.
I found out that pressing just PrtSc lets me draw an area, but I must press an extra button to "confirm" it. Just drawing the area isn't sufficient. It also stores the screenshot on disk, which I wouldn't want to do. Sure, I could set a crontab to delete all files at ~/Pictures/Screenshots every night, but it would also delete files I intended to save.
So, is there a way to replicate the old behavior?

Did you look for a Gnome Shell extension that might reproduce the old behavior?

This question is similar to: I do NOT want screenshots to be saved to file. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. The accepted answer should work with 24.04 too
